# Change "conda activate" command in terminal?

Tags: python, shell, anaconda

Can I change the command `conda activate env_name` to activate the environment?

Instead, I want to give my custom command. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *give my custom command*? Why do you want to *change the comand*? Can you add a few more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an alias, you might have to save it in your .bashrc/.bash_profile file.

```
alias <custom command>="conda activate <env name>"
```